# Restrictions on use of a commercial database in publications

Tags: copyright, databases, license

I am considering purchasing a commercial database of retail transactions for a certain industry and time period. My intent is to do basic summary statistics and regression analysis, and publish those results on an open platform (arXiv or SSRN) and ultimately submit this to a peer-reviewed journal. I don't want to publish any information that can identify individual companies in that database, let alone the entire data set.

The database vendor has a very restrictive license that mandates prior written consent of any publication based on their database.

**Questions**: does my intended use of such a database fall under a fair use policy, and do I really need to submit my draft publication for prior written consent? (I am located in the Netherlands, and the vendor is US-based and I have been in contact with their sales persons from Germany and Belgium).

Comment: I think that the specification of your jusdiction is insufficient. For example, Germany has special "copyright" laws about data bases: http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/urhg/BJNR012730965.html#BJNR012730965BJNG004301377 that are relevant for your question - and your jurisdiction may have one, too. As an example, the German law seems(!) to prohibit only substantial reproduction of the data base or reproductions that are against the interest of the database owner - so if the result of your analysis is basically what most people using the database would need, this may be a problem. But IANAL.

Comment: The EU is not a jurisdiction, and fair use is a concept that is mainly specific to the USA. You will need to be more specific about your actual jurisdiction to get a useful answer. But such a specific legal answer will likely be out of scope for this site. You need to talk to a lawyer.

Comment: One more piece of information that would be good to have here is what access you have to the database; or for what purpose you have been granted access. Are you supposed to do some specific work with the data, and now you want to also use the data for something else, namely an analysis for your research? Or have you been given access to the database in order to "use" the data in some way, as long as you do not duplicate the whole database? Or have you been granted permission only to look at the data without doing anything with it (although reasons for such a permission could be nebolous)?

Comment: @MJeffryes I was hoping to avoid lawyers as much as possible :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the database is widely advertised and commercially available. I don't have privileged access to a single company's internal data.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Ok, but for what *purpose* is it made available? What's the intention behind granting access? Answers to this question will likely be fundamentally different based upon whether availability comes with the note "Here you see the database exists, but you're not allowed to do anything with it." or with the note "Use the data for your own purposes, but do not open the whole database to outside access."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the database is sold to companies to keep track of their own sales and market share vis-a-vis competitors. So it's more like your scenario "use for your own purposes" but with the clause "do not open up anything without our consent"

Comment: I'll second MJeffryes's suggestion that you need to talk with a lawyer.  Even if you have a legal right to do this (which may or may not be the case), you'll certainly get threatening letters from the company's lawyers and you might face a lawsuit, which would be disruptive even if you win.  Furthermore, predicting whether you'll win may depend on specifics that nobody could evaluate without all the details.  (For example, your use of the term "fair use" suggests this is a copyright issue, but violating the contract with the database vendor may be a problem quite independently of copyright.)

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician ok, I get it, although it's surprising to me that not more researchers have encountered such issues and discussed them here. Could someone with enough rep close this Q as off-topic, please?